# Bluetooth Earbuds w/ Controls?

Tags: running

I'm looking for recommendations for earbuds I can wear while running and working out.  Here's my wish list of features:

- Bluetooth and compatible w/ iPhone
- Inline controls: volume, play, pause, stop
- Good battery life - should be at least 2-3 hours
- Comfortable and won't fall out while running

Price is almost not an issue at this point. Normally it would be, but I can't seem to find anything that meets the criteria above so I'm willing to spend more money if necessary.  I've done extensive research on Google, product review web sites, and individual manufacturer sites.  It appears that you can have 2 or 3 of the features above, but not all of them.

Does anyone know of "fitness-rugged" earbuds that might be good?  I want a comfortable, but secure fit, minimal cord length, inline and intuitive controls, and good battery life.

Thanks!

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic on StackExchange.